# Slack: how to get directmessage channel name

Tags: post, request, slack

I am creating a slack slash command and I want to know the username of the channel I am executing the command in.

So for example I have a colleague called `@steve`, I am directly chatting with steve and I execute the command:

```
/mycommand
```

when I check back on my application, I see that the POST request only got these values

```
[
    (u'user_id', u'U03NKXXXX'), 
    (u'channel_id', u'D03QBXXXX'), 
    (u'text', u''), (u'response_url', u'https://hooks.slack.com/commands/T03ARXXXX/3804397XXXX/nGUTg4zpQrMrRR07scI6XXXX'), 
    (u'team_id', u'T03ARXXXX'), 
    (u'channel_name', u'directmessage'), 
    (u'token', u'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'), 
    (u'command', u'/mycommand'), 
    (u'team_domain', u'myteam'), 
    (u'user_name', u'myusername')
]
```

I was expecting `directmessage` to be the name of user (`steve` on my example), so how can I get the target channel username?

Comment: thanks @smarx. Also please edit your comment, it directs to dropbox's slack support. It should this [support link](https://slack.com/help/contact)

Answer (score -2):

In theory you can take the channel ID you received from the slash request and get the full information of the current channel with [`conversations.info`](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.info), which would include the channel owner of a direct message conversation.

However, due to Slack's security architecture your token needs to have access to that direct channel. And it will only have access if it belongs to one of the two participant of that direct message channel.

So unless your app has tokens from every user the best you can do is take the user ID from the Slash command, which must come from one of the two participants of a direct message.

Comment: I don't want to identify the sender, but the directmessage channel name.

Comment: As I said, the name of a direct message channel is the same as the name of the user. So if you talk to John Doe, the name of the channel is "John Doe". Its different for group chat though, then the channel name is a list of all users attending the group chat and they are also showing up as official private channel under groups (usual direct messaging chats do not), so I would assume the slack API will also give you the channel for them. So I think I answered your question, or what am I missing here?

Comment: In my Experience @ErikKalkoken this isn't true. If "Jane Doe" is talking to "John Doe", the "channel_name" always remains "directmessage". However, the "user_name" does change based on who sent the message. So you will always know who sent the message, but it's pretty hard to find out who the recipient is. This would require decoding the "channel_id", which is what the OP is asking.

Comment: @ScottCate you are correct. I updated my answer accordingly.